# Return the end of the interval in Returning Functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In this case, [9.24. "Set Returning Functions"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html) of the PostgreSQL 9.5 manual, only the initial dates and time are returned. Is it possible to return the date and time of the end of each interval?

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2008-03-04 12:00', '10 hours');
   generate_series   
---------------------
 2008-03-01 00:00:00
 2008-03-01 10:00:00
 2008-03-01 20:00:00
 2008-03-02 06:00:00
 2008-03-02 16:00:00
 2008-03-03 02:00:00
 2008-03-03 12:00:00
 2008-03-03 22:00:00
 2008-03-04 08:00:00
(9 rows)
```

Comment: In your example, every row (except first) are " the end of each interval", it's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT gs.dte, LEAD(gs.dte) OVER (ORDER BY gs.dte) as next_dte
FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                     '2008-03-04 12:00',
                     '10 hours'
                    ) gs(dte);
```

Or, if you don't want `NULL` for the last interval, explicitly do the calculation:

```
SELECT gs.dte, (gs.dte + interval '10 hours') as end_date
FROM generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                     '2008-03-04 12:00',
                     '10 hours'
                    ) gs(dte);
```

Comment: `and end_date` should read `as end_date` or just `end_date`, I believe?